# Bokeh heat map not displaying correct results

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

I am trying to make a chloropleth map based off of bokeh's [map of US unemployment](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/0.10.0/docs/gallery/choropleth.html), and I am not very familiar with this library, although I am somewhat familiar with pandas. I have a dataframe of states and their priority for our system. I cannot get the priorities to display correctly. I think I am using the fill_color attribute incorrectly but I can't find any more information about it other than the [one line](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/0.10.0/docs/user_guide/styling.html#fill-properties) listed in the bokeh docs.

My expected output is for high-priority states to appear red, medium-priority states to appear green, and low-priority states to appear yellow. (The color scheme was not my choice.) If the states do not have a priority, they should appear white. However, the output doesn't match that at all-- the colors seem to be randomly placed. Some low-priority states are red and some are yellow; some medium-priority states are white and some are red; etc.

I think the error lies in my `state_colors` list. Right now I'm looping through it and updating it with each state's priority, but for some reason it is not updating correctly. Is there a way to change the `fill_color` attribute within the patches() method so that the color corresponds to the priority value? Or am I just messing up the `state_colors` list somehow?

```
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.sampledata import us_states
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_file
import pandas as pd

df2 = pd.read_excel(filename, sheetname='2012 Master', header=1, skip_footer=4, parse_cols='A,B,L,P')

usa_states = us_states.data.copy()
state_xs = [usa_states[code]["lons"] for code in usa_states]
state_ys = [usa_states[code]["lats"] for code in usa_states]
df2.fillna(value="", inplace=True)

state_colors = []
for state in df2["State"]:
    for priority in df2["Priority"]:
        if priority == "High":
            state_colors.append("#FF0000")
        elif priority == "Medium":
            state_colors.append("#008000")
        elif priority == "Low":
            state_colors.append("#FFFF00")    
    else:
        state_colors.append("#FFFFFF")

source = ColumnDataSource(
    data=dict(
        st = df2['State'],
        priority = df2['Priority']
    )
)
p = figure(title="Title", tools= TOOLS, toolbar_location="above", plot_width=1100, plot_height=700, x_range=[-128,-64], y_range=[23,50])

p.patches(state_xs, state_ys, fill_color = state_colors, source=source, fill_alpha=1, line_color="black", line_width=1)
hover = p.select(dict(type=HoverTool))
hover.tooltips= [
    ("State","@st"),
    ("Priority","@priority"),
]
show(p)
```

My dataframe (df2):

```
State       Priority
Alabama     Low
Arizona 
Arkansas    
California  Medium
Colorado    
Connecticut 
Delaware    
District of Columbia    
Florida     High
Georgia     Medium
Idaho       High
Illinois    Low
...
Wisconsin   High
Wyoming     Low
```

I am using pandas 0.17.1. [Here](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/bokeh/sampledata/us_states.py) is the usa_states code that bokeh uses. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBavN.png) is my current output.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using pandas badly with your state_colors list.

try to replace your loops with something like that :

```
def get_color(priority):
    if priority == "High":
        return "#FF0000"
    elif priority == "Medium":
        return "#008000"
    elif priority == "Low":
        return "#FFFF00"  
    else:
        return "#FFFFFF"

df2["color"] = df2["Priority"].apply(get_color)
```

and then replace source by

```
source = ColumnDataSource(
    data=dict(
        st = df2['State'],
        priority = df2['Priority'],
        state_colors = df2['color']
    )
)
```

Here is a piece of code that works for circles, not tested for patches.

```
df1['color'] = df1['value'].apply(lambda value: rgb2hex(m.to_rgba(value)))
df1['alpha'] = 0.3

output_notebook()

source1 = ColumnDataSource(data = dict(
    longitude = df1['longitude'],
    latitude = df1['latitude'],
    color = df1['color'],
    alpha = df1['alpha']
))

# The Google Maps plot
x_range = Range1d()
y_range = Range1d()
style = [{"stylers":[{"hue":"#ff1a00"},{"invert_lightness":True},{"saturation":-100},{"lightness":33},{"gamma":0.5}]},{"featureType":"water","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#2D333C"}]}]
map_style = json.dumps(style)
map_options = GMapOptions(lat=40.7339773,  lng=-73.9888841, zoom=13, map_type="roadmap"), styles=map_style)
plot = GMapPlot(x_range=x_range, y_range=y_range, map_options=map_options, plot_width=1000, plot_height=700, 
                title="my title")
plot.title_text_font_size = '1em'

circle = Circle(x="longitude", y="latitude", size=10, fill_color="color", line_color="black", fill_alpha="alpha", line_alpha=0)
plot.add_glyph(source1, circle)

pantool = PanTool()
wheelzoomtool = WheelZoomTool()
plot.add_tools(pantool, wheelzoomtool) 

show(plot)
```